# Comparing 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries in Python. One is a list of teams and their ranks in a league table, with each team being a key and their ranks being the associated value. The other is data about each team, with the team name being a value of a key:

```
RankDict = {'Tigers':'1','Lions':'2', 'Pumas':'3', 'Wolves':'4'}

TeamDict = {'TeamRecords':[{'Team': 'Lions', 'Location':'Greenville', 
             'HomeGround':'Trec Park', 'Coach': 'K. Wilson'},
            {'Team':'Pumas', 'Location':'Fairlodge', 
             'HomeGround':'Fairlodge Fields', 'Coach':'G. Kennedy'}]}
```

What I want to do is print the details from the `TeamDict` dictionary based on the rank associated with the team in the `RankDict` but can't just do a straight key comparison because the keys aren't common. Can anyone help me out?

I can't find anything regarding this type of dictionary comparison in the documentation. Maybe it isn't even possible?

Comment: `TeamDict` is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: @adohertyd: Before your edit, `TeamDict` wasn't a valid dictionary, but a valid set literal.  After your edit, it's neither.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it is meant to be a dictionary. Why is this not a valid dictionary? The key is `TeamRecords` and the values are dictionaries. Should the nested dicts be in a list?

Comment: @adohertyd: The key is missing for the dictionary with the Pumas team.

Comment: @adohertyd - please save your code into a file and run it in python interpreter. If the interpreter doesn't accept it (run without error), then we cannot neither.

Comment: "What I want to do is print the details from the TeamDict dictionary based on the rank associated with the team" In what way based on the rank?

Comment: @eumiro I made the nested dictionaries a list and I can print the `TeamDict` from the interpreter

Comment: Why bother using a dict for TeamDict at all? Why not just use the value associated with 'TeamRecords' as a list directly?

Comment: @Strigoides I start with the `TeamDict` only that has about 40 teams and many attributes for each team. The above is a tiny sample. I create a list of the teams from the team dict and rank them using a formula. Then I want to print the team details in rank order from the list. I wanted to keep the maths element as simple as possible so only used the team names

Comment: @adohertyd Regardless of the number of teams you have, I can't think of anything you could do with `a_dict = {'list_name':a_list}` that you couldn't do more simply with `list_name = a_list`

Comment: I do start with a list but the function I use returns an ordered dictionary, hence the dictionary comparisons

Comment: @adohertyd I see. In that case I would still be inclined to get the list from the dict that is returned (`list_name = function_returning_dict()["list_name"]`) rather than dealing with it as a dict.

Comment: @Strigoides will have a look at doing that. I'm trying to avoid dictionaries where possible anyway. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will print the team, the rank and the team details (sorted by rank):

```
import operator

RecordsByTeam = {}
for r in TeamDict['TeamRecords']:
    RecordsByTeam[r['Team']] = r

for team, rank in sorted(RankDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print team
    print rank
    try:        
        print RecordsByTeam[team]
    except KeyError:
        print 'No details could be found for team', team
```

Note that I'm doing a `try/except` when printing the team details because `TeamDict` does not contain information about each team.

Also note that you should use integers for the ranks in `RankDict`, otherwise the above code won't sort properly when there is a team with, e.g., `'11'` as rank (it will sort: `'11'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`).

Comment: Thanks very much Simeon I think this is what I am looking for. I only printed a tiny part of the actual dictionaries for a sample but I will be using the try/except function anyway. Also, will take into account the point about the integers thank you